# why does this loop always return the original argument?

Tags: python, django, loops

I've a loop which checks a username.
If the username exists I want to increment the counter for each loop.
Then append that Id to the username.

This loop always returns the original argument passed though and I don't know why. I have it going on a `def save` on my form in forms.py.

```
def check_username(self, username):
    """
    check if username is taken. if it is then increment the counter and append to the username
    """
    counter = 001
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
        counter += 1
        username += str(counter)
        self.check_username(username)
    return username
```

Comment: You are doing an if, that's not a loop. You should use a while.

Comment: Haha you're right it's not a loop... But I was looping back to the same def. However a while loop is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `return self.check_username(username)` within the `if` block, otherwise, your recursive call won't do much.

The counter is probably not used as you'd like here either. You'll keep adding '2' at the end of every username you try, e.g `username` -> `username2` -> `username22`.

This being said, a `while` loop would certainly be easier to read here. I'd try something like this:

```
def check_username(self, username):
    counter = 1
    new_username = username
    while not User.objects.filter(username__iexact=new_username).exists():
        counter += 1
        new_username = username + str(counter)
    return new_username
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the validity of your `if User.objects...` condition because `username` should change if it ever gets in that block.